# Strange error when running a tensor flow classifier fit

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I am trying to make a simple model based on training and testing images i have stored locally. I have followed the guide found here: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers but have begun editing the code to serve my own needs and use the images I have stored locally instead of ones loaded from somewhere.

```
mnist_classifier = learn.Estimator(
      model_fn=cnn_model_fn, model_dir="/tmp/mnist_convnet_model")


tensors_to_log = {"probabilities": "softmax_tensor"}
logging_hook = tf.train.LoggingTensorHook(
      tensors=tensors_to_log, every_n_iter=50)

testData = []
testLabels = []
for filename in os.listdir('images'):
    im = cv2.imread('images/' + filename)
    testData.append(im)
    testLabels.append(np.int32(1.0))

for filename in os.listdir('notImages'):
    im = cv2.imread('notImages/' + filename)
    testData.append(im)
    testLabels.append(np.int32(0.0))

evalTestData = []
evalTestLabels = []
for filename in os.listdir('evalImages'):
    im = cv2.imread('evalImages/' + filename)
    evalTestData.append(im)
    evalTestLabels.append(np.int32(1.0))

for filename in os.listdir('evalNotImages'):
    im = cv2.imread('evalNotImages/' + filename)
    evalTestData.append(im)
    evalTestLabels.append(np.int32(0.0))

testData = np.array(testData)
testLabels = np.array(testLabels)
evalTestData = np.array(evalTestData)
evalTestLabels = np.array(evalTestLabels)

mnist_classifier.fit(
      x=testData,
      y=testLabels,
      batch_size=10,
      steps=20000,
      monitors=[logging_hook])
```

It seems this fit command then kicks off the following code:

```
input_layer = tf.reshape(features, [-1, -1, -1, 3])

conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(
      inputs=input_layer,
      filters=32,
      kernel_size=[5, 5],
      padding="same",
      activation=tf.nn.relu)
```

This tf.layers.conv2d thing seems to be causing a crash as i get the following error:

```
File "cnn_mnist.py", line 37, in cnn_model_fn
    activation=tf.nn.relu)

TypeError: Value passed to parameter 'input' has DataType string not in list of allowed values: float16, float32, float64
```

I have tried to do a bit of googling but can't find people talking about this issue specifically. Obviously something is a string that shouldn't be. It seems something I changed about this code to make it use local images has broken something that I am not correcting for. Any ideas?

Edit: I printed the type of the features variable and it said it was a Tensor. I then printed the tensor and got this:

```
Tensor("input:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=string)
```

This dtype should NOT be string and the shape is wrong. Seems like this is probably creating my error. Any ideas on how to fix it???

Comment: First check your `testData, testLabels, evalTestData, evalTestLabels`, to make sure they are all numbers or not.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding the following line:

```
input_layer = tf.to_float(input_layer)
```